# How to ignore specific type of files to download in wget?

Tags: command-line, wget

How do I ignore `.jpg`, `.png` files in `wget` as I wanted to include only `.html` files.

I am trying:

```
wget  -R index.html,*tiff,*pdf,*jpg -m http://example.com/
```

but it's not working.

Comment: `wget *.html -m http://web.123.org` ? Offtopic question.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Use the

```
 --reject jpg,png  --accept html
```

options to exclude/include files with certain extensions, see http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Recursive-Accept_002fReject-Options.

Put patterns with wildcard characters in quotes, otherwise your shell will expand them, see http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Types-of-Files

Comment: This question is half duplicate to http://superuser.com/questions/487198/exclude-list-of-specific-files-in-wget

Answer (score 17):

```
# -r : recursive    
# -nH : Disable generation of host-prefixed directories
# -nd : all files will get saved to the current directory
# -np : Do not ever ascend to the parent directory when retrieving recursively. 
# -R : don't download files with this files pattern
# -A : get only *.html files (for this case)
```

**For instance:**

```
wget -r -nH -nd -np -A "*.html" -R "*.gz, *.tar"  http://www1.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/noaa/1990/
```

Comment: Why -1 to that answer? I'm not posted, but I don't see why it's downvoted.

Comment: no idea, I've been looking for -nd option which is not listed in 'Recursive Retrieval Options' in manual, so upvoted

Comment: I believe `-A *.html` is an error -- it will get expanded by the shell. I should be `-A "*.html"`.

Comment: All of the uses of `*` without quoting may be intercepted by the shell, if a local file matches them, and should be quoted.

Answer (score 2):

Worked example to download all files excluding archives:

```
wget -r -k -l 7 -E -nc \
 -R "*.gz, *.tar, *.tgz, *.zip, *.pdf, *.tif, *.bz, *.bz2, *.rar, *.7z" \
 -erobots=off \
 --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36" \
 http://misis.ru/
```

Answer (score 1):

this is what I get from `wget --help`:

```
Recursive accept/reject:
  -A,  --accept=LIST               comma-separated list of accepted extensions.
  -R,  --reject=LIST               comma-separated list of rejected extensions.
       --accept-regex=REGEX        regex matching accepted URLs.
       --reject-regex=REGEX        regex matching rejected URLs.
       --regex-type=TYPE           regex type (posix|pcre).
  -D,  --domains=LIST              comma-separated list of accepted domains.
       --exclude-domains=LIST      comma-separated list of rejected domains.
       --follow-ftp                follow FTP links from HTML documents.
       --follow-tags=LIST          comma-separated list of followed HTML tags.
       --ignore-tags=LIST          comma-separated list of ignored HTML tags.
  -H,  --span-hosts                go to foreign hosts when recursive.
  -L,  --relative                  follow relative links only.
  -I,  --include-directories=LIST  list of allowed directories.
  --trust-server-names             use the name specified by the redirection
                                   url last component.
  -X,  --exclude-directories=LIST  list of excluded directories.
  -np, --no-parent                 don't ascend to the parent directory.
```

so you can use `-R` or `--reject` to reject extentions this way:

```
wget -R="index.html,*.tiff,*.pdf,*.jpg" http://example.com/
```

and in my case here is final command which I wanted to recursively download/update none-html files from an indexed website directory:

```
wget -N -r -np -nH --cut-dirs=3 -nv -R="*.htm*,*.html" http://example.com/1/2/3/
```